# Definition of Connection

Tags: iis, iis-5

Does anyone know what constitutes an official connection to a workstation? I have a reasonably small scale operation where I am using a WORKSTATION, not server, as a server. For the most part, it works fine, but there is a 10 connection limit and I was toying with some new functionality and ended up causing some problems as the 10 connection limit kept getting hit.

From trial and error, I am pretty sure using a web service on a workstation counts as a connection as would surfing web pages served by the workstation. What if I set-up a MySql database? Everytime a PC connects or replicates data from the MySql server, would THAT count as a connection? What about connecting to the PC via mapping a drive?

Comment: I would try SO's sister site http://serverfault.com with this one.

Answer (score 0):

These two articles should help:

> [Understanding IIS7 Request Restrictions on Windows Vista](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2008/05/01/understanding-iis7-request-restrictions-on-windows-vista.aspx)
>
> [IIS limits imposed by Operating System version](http://www.jpelectron.com/sample/WWW%20and%20HTML/IIS-%20OS%20Version%20Limits.htm)

Basically from Vista on the number of connections are unlimited. It's the number of of concurrent requests that IIS can process that are restricted. So in theory you could have 15 concurrent connections to IIS but five of them are queued.